How to push changes to the default repo of a GitLab pipeline?
I would like to push changes made by a GitLab pipeline job to its default repository.
My code is the following:
git config user.name "GitLab CI"
git config user.email "ci-bot@${CI_SERVER_FQDN}"
git remote set-url origin "https://${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"
git checkout ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
echo "This is a change" >>change.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Commit message for the changes."
git push origin ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}

I get the following error message:
+ git push origin main
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://[MASKED]@<my-server-fqdn>': No such device or address

I also tried to prefix $CI_JOB_TOKEN with "oauth2:":
git remote set-url origin "https://oauth2:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"

But then I get:
+ git push origin main
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. If a password was provided for Git authentication, the password was incorrect or you're required to use a token instead of a password. If a token was provided, it was either incorrect, expired, or improperly scoped.

I unprotected the main branch of my test project to make sure that access is not denied because of pushing to a protected branch with a job token.
I checked the value of $CI_JOB_TOKEN which looks like a real token:
glcbt-64_not-the-realtoken...

Note that it works with a project access token but I'd like to make a reusable component and, therefore, avoid those who reuse to create such tokens.
Any idea?

HAve you read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#allow-git-push-requests-to-your-project-repository

You are right. I did see the page but didn't realised that this functionality was subject to the activation of a feature flag (allow_push_repository_for_job_token), which I cannot do myself as I am not an administrator. I now understand why I didn't find the Allow Git push requests to the repository option under Job token permissions. I will wait for this feature to be rolled out, which seems to be imminent. Thanks!
